# Data from Plist is Incorrectly Ordered in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

I have data that is stored in a plist but when I pull it to my UITableView it gets reordered for some reason. Here are my table view data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.lunch_Dinner count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.lunch_Dinner allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *typeOfEntree = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return [[self.lunch_Dinner valueForKey:typeOfEntree] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EntreeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *typeOfEntree = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *entree = [[self.lunch_Dinner valueForKey:typeOfEntree] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = entree;

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the order of the plist:

- Appetizers
- Soups
- Pastas
- Pizzas
- Specials

And this is the resulting order in the UITableView after being compiled:

- Pizzas
- Soups
- Appetizers
- Pastas
- Specials

Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why store something that doesn't change?  Hard code the list in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store table in plist it is better to consider the following structure:

```
NSArray *sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:row_1, row_2, ... , nil] 
            forKey:@"section name 1"],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:row_1, row_2, ... , nil] 
            forKey:@"section name 2"],
    ...
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:row_1, row_2, ... , nil] 
            forKey:@"section name N"], 
    nil];
```

This code representation is easy to reproduce as plist. Create it as in example below

[image]

This structure can be easily used as UITableView datasource

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.datasource count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:section];
    return [dict.allKeys lastObject];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:section];
    return [dict.allValues.lastObject count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    id cellPresenter = [dict.allValues.lastObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since this is coded in instead of a plist I wouldn't be able to store the plist in a server for constant updating. I would need to submit an update to Apple instead. Or am I not understanding?

Comment: This structure can be reprodused by plist. Look at the answer update

Comment: I understand, thanks for the clarification. I changed my plist using your structure. Do I need to update the data source methods now? Thanks

Comment: I hope now you've got the idea. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `lunch_Dinner` is a `NSDictionary`. `NSDictionary`s are unordered, so you are not guaranteed a specific output order from them.

It is a little hard to see exactly what value you're getting from having a key/value pair here, but one option would be to keep a separate `NSArray` with the correct ordering, and use that to correctly populate things.

Comment: Yes it is an NSDictionary. I tried to change the `NSDictionary` to `NSArray` and load the plist with `arrayWithContentsOfFile` like I did with the the dictionary but now when I compile nothing appears in the UITableView. Is there something else I need to change in the data source methods or is simply changing the dictionary to an array not possible? @Adam

Comment: The keys of the plist were arrays to begin with. @Adam