# How to specify the number of rows per section

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a NSDictionary returning which I would like to have a row for each entry, however I also want a section above this section with only one etry, I am trying to do this with the code below but I keep getting an error when I go to enter the if statement.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // returns the number of rows per section based off each entry in letterDictionary
    NSString *currentLetter = [sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];
    if (section == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    return [[letterDictionary objectForKey:currentLetter] count];
}
```

this is the error I recive when I try to set up the first section of the tableview.

```
2012-08-20 16:12:11.983 kPad[5681:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3686756b 0x36b4797f 0x367a856d 0x56c11 0x3793f8b7 0x37940c19 0x37940b6d 0x3794075d 0x5826d 0x57dfb 0x5569b 0x55ee9 0x5fd65 0x32d8bead 0x373f3ccb 0x5f6a5 0x61c99 0x5f531 0x5ef6f 0x5b443 0x374105b5 0x37361991 0x373618ad 0x32ccaacf 0x32cca1bb 0x32cf2323 0x367ae2e1 0x32cf2783 0x32c56c65 0x36838143 0x368379a9 0x368366ef 0x367b4c1d 0x367b4aa9 0x3967833b 0x3791e535 0x4edd5 0x3557fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

the issue is is that there can be several sections and it is dynamic.. thats why i use an if else.. I hope this is the right thing to do. its just i keep reciving the error.

Comment: The issue is because you set the number of sections to 1 but you do not set the number of rows to 0. I recommend you to look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892598/data-from-plist-is-incorrectly-ordered-in-uitableview/11892852#11892852 for the complete solution

Comment: Hi the error shows that you have only 1 section in your table. Please check your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method and what it returns in its `return` statement it must be 1. And yes the section index is starting with 0 not with 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that sectionLetterArray doesn't have an index of 1, so it crashes. You can remove your else statement (it won't get executed if the section is 1 since you already return something), and replace it with `NSString *currentLetter = [sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];`

**EDIT:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // returns the number of rows per section based off each entry in letterDictionary

    if (section == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    NSString *currentLetter = [sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[letterDictionary objectForKey:currentLetter] count];
}
```

Comment: gah.. still trying to figure out what you mean inbetweened the failed attempts at reworking the code :P

Comment: I am trying to use your answer at the moment, however although `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is returning 2, the only code to ever be executed  in `numberOfRowsInSection` is the if statement the second piece of that code is never executed... I have no idea why, this is very confusing.

Comment: So i have figured out that the letterDictionary still starts from 0.. thats why I am only getting one or the other returning.. I need to find a way of inserting into the begining of my letterDictionary

Answer (score 0):

first put the `section == 0` in your if statement and also check the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method does this **return 2** in `return` statement of this method? If so you can have `section == 1` otherwise it has only one section and it is **== 0** not **== 1**

other then this all is fine :)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Something weird is happening here.. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is defiantly returning 2 however, in `numberOfRowsInSection:` if (section == 0) is never entered. and when it goes to return it crashes with the same error code

Comment: Oh k.. Then does `sectionLetterArray` is mutableArray and does it is init well and have any member? Please check it's length ie count of this array there seems the error root from the error code. :) Please let me now about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check how many item in your array `sectionLetterArray` and how many sections do u have in your row...

Comment: in numberOfSectionsInTableView I am returning 2 sections

Comment: it is dynamic.. so it changes depending on the results returning.. Thats the cause of this issue. I think however I am going to go for a static button in the navigation bar for this now as its turning out to be too hard.. I have spent almost two whole days on this :P

Comment: may be its due to your accessing  array with wrong index...just debugs it and check array count and section number....or you can send code to me i will check it...